# $_POST is empty on XAMPP when post from remote form

Tags: php, apache, variables, xampp

I have a Windows VPS server, this server is a personal server so I installed XAMPP for running PHP and Apache on this server.

Now I created a from with post method on another server and I post data to this persoanl server (which have XAMPP).

when I use `$_POST` this variable is empty, I checked the `$_REQUEST` too but this variable is empty too.

Local forms don't have this problem and `$_POST` will pass all posted variables, I have this problem just in remote forms.

I think this problem is related to security and I should change it on `php.ini`, But I don't know what should I do!

**UPDATE:**

HTML CODE:

```
<form method="post" action="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="Username ..." />
  <br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="Password ..." />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

PHP CODE :

```
<?php

echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_POST['password'];
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($GLOBALS);

?>
```

If both file located on same server php file will work and `$_POST` will return posted variables, but if HTML file located on different server, `$_POST` will empty !

Comment: Show the code you use to post.

Comment: Cross-Domain Policies where enrolled after forms so you are allowed to post to another domain. Like @BartFriederichs said: Plase show your code.

Comment: As far as I know PHP doesn't have a native mechanism to prevent this. Does that bundle you are using provide a security module such as Suhosin or mod_security?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario hmmm, I don't know, I installed a fresh XAMPP package, (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) I didn't install any extension and I didn't change anything in php.ini

Comment: Is this perhaps helping: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1221 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess. Maybe you forgot to set the method in your form.

```
<form method="post" action="http://somepage.com/">
```

And to make sure that the post array in the receiving end is not empty, you also need some input fields with a defined name.

```
<input type="text" name="my_value" value="test value" />
```

On the receiving server print_r($_POST) should then create something like:

```
Array
(
    [my_value] => test value
)
```

Comment: In my question I said this form don't have problem when is on local server, just have problem when located on remote server.

Comment: That's a bit strange. I just tried with a fresh not modified install of XAMPP and here it works just find.